# Sharepoint online manifest file export

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

Is there a way to export the Online site (SharePoint Online) like one done in Onpermises using a power shell script "Export-SpWeb "http://AAAAA:28769/sites/TargetSite" -ItemUrl "/sites/TargetSite/GA folder" -NoFileCompression -Path "E:\Temp"
"

which export all the xmls for the particular site ?

Or is there any alternative to view those xmls including manifest.xml using any tools or something like that ??

Answer (score 0):

Use the [OfficeDevPnP.PowerShell commands](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-PowerShell) from the [PnP provisioning framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/pnp-provisioning-framework) to extract and reuse site templates for SharePoint Online and Office 365.

Here is a starting summary description on MSDN of the [PnP remote provisioning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/pnp-remote-provisioning) resources on GitHub.

Example:

```
Connect-SPOnline [mySourceUrl]
Get-SPOProvisioningTemplate -Out demo.xml
Connect-SPOnline [myDestinationUrl]
Apply-SPOProvisioningTemplate -Path .\demo.xml
```